# How to display message in shopify store using app?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api-node

I want to create a simple Shopify app. In Shopify admin, I'm creating one form with one filed like message and display to front store.

Here My question where can I store message data in admin Shopify and how to display that data in-store.